# Run php script every x mins using ajax request

Tags: javascript

got this file 'functions.php':

```
<?php
function test ($url){
$starttime = microtime(true);
$valid = @fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$stoptime = microtime(true);
echo (round(($stoptime-$starttime)*1000)).' ms.';

if (!$valid) {
   echo "Status - Failure";
} else {
   echo "Status - Success";
}
}
    test('google.com');
?>
```

I want to run it every 10seconds or so, i was told to use ajax request but i dont completely understand how it works. I tried creating a new file 'index.php', and then had this written in it:

```
<script>
var milliSeconds = 10000; 
setInterval( function() {
    //Ajax request, i dont know how to write it
    xmlhttp.open("POST","functions.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}, milliSeconds);
</script>
```

I put both files into ftp but nothing happens, can someone help me write a propper ajax request?

Edit: eddited typo, still doesnt work tho

Comment: sounds like you should have a look into the "body onload" functionality to trigger your loop ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp )

Comment: @Najzero you are right, it may fail several times before dom is loaded, but after that?

Comment: @Najzero: do us all a favour and don't link http://w3fools.com as reference. @user1894929 you got a typo in your `.open()` call.

Comment: @jAndy - I never cease to learn new stuff - like the connection between W3 and W3schools. Web stuff was more of a hobby (yeah that nasty php3 past every c++ developer - like me - refuses to mention) to me... and to be honest, the original from w3 is a bit harder to understand: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var milliSeconds = 1000;

setInterval( function() {

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         console.log ( xmlhttp.responseText );
      } 
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","functions.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();


}, milliSeconds);
```

You have to load xmlhttp request object according to the browser ( `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();` ), then set an event handler when the xmlhttp state changes ( `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` ). When it changes check if the status is 200 (success) then do whatever you want with the response. ( I printed it to console )

Answer (score 1):

So, it sounds like your only problem is that you don't know how to write an XHR request. Take a look at [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Comment on this answer with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","funkction.php",true);
```

should be:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","functions.php",true);
```